Kotlin: Handling star projected generics with type tokens
Consider the following generic class which is "reified" by using a type token:
class Gen<X : Any>(val token: KClass<X>) {
    fun doSomething(x: X) {
        // ...
    }
}

Now Gen is used heterogeneously using star projection but the type token can be used to match fitting values:
fun m(g: Gen<*>, x: Any) {
    if (g.token == x::class) {
        g.doSomething(x)
    }
}

This does not compile. Introducing the following unchecked cast makes the code compile, but is unsafe as the cast value can be fed with the wrong input (the current code does not actually throw ClassCastException but can easily be extended to do so).
fun m(g: Gen<*>, x: Any) {
    if (g.token == x::class) {
        g as Gen<Any>
        g.doSomething(x)
        g.doSomething(8) // potential ClassCastException
    }
}

Is this the only way to handle this or are there more type safe ways to do it?

Refinement
Introducing a "dynamic type" improves the situation
fun <T : Any> m(g: Gen<*>, x: T) {
    if (g.token == x::class) {
        g as Gen<T>

        g.doSomething(x) // ok
        g.doSomething(8) // does not compile
    }
}

The condition in if together with the cast reflects the purpose of the type token and after that, we are again in a "safe" code. However, it would be desirable that the business logic is decoupled from the check/cast and that the latter could somehow be encapsulated. This seems to be not that easy. For example, the following approach is "unsafe".
fun <T : Any> Gen<*>.ifMatches(x: T, code: (Gen<T>) -> Unit) {
    if (token == x::class) {
        code(this as Gen<T>)
    }
}

fun main() {
    val g: Gen<*> = Gen(String::class)
    val x: Any = "hello"
    g.ifMatches(x) { it.doSomething(8) } // potential ClassCastException
}  


Thanks to broot, I guess I have found a solution which I was seeking for.
interface TypedCode {
    fun <T : Any> Gen<T>.invoke(value: T) {
}

fun Gen<*>.runIfMatches(value: Any, code: TypedCode) {
    if (token == value::class) {
        this as Gen<Any>
        with(code) { invoke(value) }
    } 
}

fun main() {
    val g: Gen<*> = Gen(String::class)
    val a: Any = "hello"
    g.runIfMatches(a, object : TypedCode {
        override fun <T : Any> Gen<T>.invoke(value: T) {
            doSomething(value) // compiles and executes
        }
    })
    g.runIfMatches(a, object : TypedCode {
        override fun <T : Any> Gen<T>.invoke(value: T) {
            doSomething(8) // does not compile
        }
    })
    g.runIfMatches(8, object : TypedCode {
        override fun <T : Any> Gen<T>.invoke(value: T) {
            doSomething(value) // compiles but does not execute
        }
    })
}

The runIfMatches function encapsulates the guarantees made by the runtime type token in a (necessarily) unsafe code. The business logic is decoupled from this and runs in a safe environment.
Syntactically it is not ideal, but probably a limitation of the language.

As a rule of thumb, the code that understands the logic inside the Gen and performs unchecked casts should be "close" to it. It could be a member function or extension function provided by the same component. In many cases there is no need to use any sophisticated ways to handle type safety, because the code that does the unchecked cast is already double checked by a developer for correctness.
But if we need to provide some utils for type safety, for example for consumers of our class, then depending on the case, there are some techniques we can apply.
If we need to provide a type safe doSomething function for users of the Gen, we can implement it easily:
fun Gen<*>.doSomethingIfMatches(x: Any) {
    if (token == x::class) {
        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        (this as Gen<Any>).doSomething(x)
    }
}

If we implement an internal function, close to Gen, so we are generally fine with making unchecked casts, but we would like to restrict the untyped code to only the beginning of the function and then follow with a type safe code, we can make the function generic and use T as a "dynamic type":
fun <T : Any> m(g: Gen<*>, x: T) {
    if (g.token == x::class) {
        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        g as Gen<T>
        g.doSomething(x)
        g.doSomething(8) // compile error
    }
}

If we have multiple functions consuming or returning X and we need an utility to switch from untyped to typed code environment, we can do this:
fun main() {
    val g: Gen<*> = Gen(String::class)
    g.asTypedOrNull<String>()?.doSomething("hello") // executes
    g.asTypedOrNull<Int>()?.doSomething(42) // doesn't execute
}

@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
inline fun <reified T : Any> Gen<*>.asTypedOrNull(): Gen<T>? = (this as Gen<T>).takeIf { token == T::class }

Please note contrary to other examples, the above uses the compile-time type, not a runtime type.
If we need to base the logic on runtime types, we could think about an util which accepts an lambda, and executes it conditionally, passing Gen and x of matching types. However, I don't know a way to represent such login in Kotlin. It should be something similar to:
fun main() {
    val g: Gen<*> = Gen(String::class)
    g.ifMatches("hello") { doSomething(it) } // executes
    g.ifMatches(42) { doSomething(it) } // doesn't execute
}

inline fun Gen<*>.ifMatches(x: Any, block: <T> Gen<T>.(T) -> Unit): Unit { // syntax error
    if (token == x::class) {
        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        (this as Gen<T>).block(x as T)
    }
}

But obviously, this doesn't compile. We can't make the whole ifMatches generic, because this way the caller controls T and this is not what we need.

Thanks for the explanations. It allowed me to think further and refine the goals of my question, see "Refinement".

Ahh, you are right, the last example is not correct. I'll remove it from my answer.

Nice, thanks to to our interaction, I guess I found a solution for me, see my answer. If you see further improvements, let me know.
